# A crossing point of two probability distribution functions (CDFs) as estimate of their joint PDF?

Tags: distributions, self-study, joint-distribution

I have stumbled at interesting (to me) phenomenon. Imagine I have quantile estimates of a probability distribution function (a CDF, to be clear) of variables `X1` and `X2`. They are approximately normal (more or less). I assume `X1` is independent of `X2`.

I plotted them on one chart, where for `X1` it reads "probability that X1 >= x is ..." and for `X2` "probability that X2 <= x is ...". Like that:

[image]

Then I wondered whether I can estimate a joint PDF of the variables to answer the question "what is the probability X1 >= X2?". In my task I cannot estimate the joint PDF explicitly, so that I could sum up the densities below/under an abline. I only have marginal distributions.

So I run a simulation:

```
sims <- numeric()

cros <- numeric()

qs <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)

for(
    i in 1:10000
)
{
    m1 <- runif(1, -1, 1)

    m2 <- runif(1, -1, 1)

    x1 <- rnorm(10000, m1, 1)

    x2 <- rnorm(10000, m2, 1)

    sims <- 
        c(
            sims
            , mean(x1 > x2)
        )

    p1 <- qnorm(qs, mean = m1, sd = 1, lower.tail = F, log.p = FALSE)

    p2 <- qnorm(qs, mean = m2, sd = 1, lower.tail = T, log.p = FALSE)

    #plot(p1, qs, xlim = c(-3,3));points(p2,qs,col='red')

    for(
        i in seq_along(qs)
    )
    {

        if(
            p1[i] < p2[i]
        )
        {

            cros <- 
                c(
                    cros
                    , qs[i]
                )

            break

        }

    }

}

plot(sims, cros); abline(col = 'red')

dt = data.table(sims = sims, cros = cros)

summary(lm(sims~cros-1, dt))
```

That showed that my guess was approximately right:

[image]

What bothers me, though, is they are not *really* linearly dependent.

```
Call:
lm(formula = sims ~ cros - 1, data = dt)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.10080 -0.05865 -0.01542  0.02847  0.07024 

Coefficients:
     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
cros 1.018356   0.001379   738.3   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.05135 on 4999 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9909,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9909 
F-statistic: 5.451e+05 on 1 and 4999 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**So, question is: Can one use the crossing point of two probability distribution functiuons legitimately as an estimate of their joint PDF in absence of the real PDF?**

Comment: @Konstantin, could you tell me what confuses you? Is it not clear question or the whole idea?

Comment: 1. Probability distribution function is a vague term. You write pdf everywhere - that's normally probability density function, but you plot cdf - cumulative density function. 2. You are mentioning joint-density function, a function of two variables, but $P(X_1>X_2)$ is just a number.

Comment: And if you take your time to downvote, I would appreciate if you give me a line on why you think it is worhless question, please.

Comment: @Konstantin, I edited the title, mentioning CDF. I mean CDF by probability distribution. I specifically write PDF when I mean probability density function. I though it as clear enough. So the question is exactly about estimating a joint PDF given marginal CDFs.

Comment: A crossing point of two cdfs is always going to be just a _single_ point. And you're talking about a bi-variate joint pdf.

Comment: Another thing to think of: for a bivariate distribution with normal marginals, you cannot say if it is normal. Co-dependence between the variables is key. And your conjecture is based on simulation of two independent normals (looks like, you didn't really explain what you're doing, a comment could help)

Comment: @Konstantin, thanks for your interest. Let me explain. Suppose I am given a bi-variate PDF. I can then sum up the densitties below or under the abline (x1=x2) to get "the probability that X1 > X2" after rescaling to probabilities. I don't have the joint PDF. But I need to find the "the probability that X1 > X2". My attempt showed that using the Y-axis value of probability (as whown in first chart) at exactly the crossing point of two CDFs is approximately answering my question. Am I right or wrong?

Comment: @Konstantin, to "And your conjecture is based on simulation of two independent normals (looks like, you didn't really explain what you're doing, a comment could help)". I assumed the variables are independent (written in my question). They can only differ in mean and standard deviation.

Comment: @Konstantin, nice to know we speak Russian. Привет. ) Look at line 3: "I assume X1 is independent of X2." I added that in an edit. Is it clear this time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108704/discussion-between-konstantin-and-alexey-burnakov).